# Can Apache JMeter be used to measure the load time for a specific action

Tags: jmeter, performance

I am new to performance testing. Can Apache JMeter be used to measure the load time for a specific action, such as response time for a button click by simultaneous users. If yes how this is performed using JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to performance testing!!

First, you have to be clear about that a specific action (like a button click) is a **POST** request. So, if you want to measure the Response time of that request, just add a **HTTP sampler** in your test script in which you will use **Method: POST**. You can send some parameters manually!!!

You can make your script manually or either use [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).

To see your results, add a listener like **View Results Tree** in your script and then run your test.

It is suggested that For the very first time you should use these values In the **Thread Group** section :

**Number of threads (users)= 1,Ramp-Up Period=1,Loop count=1**

You can start making your script like this:

[image]

Hope, this will satisfy your query!! If you need any other help, I will be happy to help you.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

Well I don't think JMeter will help you do performance or load testing of the click action/event of a button. If the click of a button makes an HTTP request to the server, then you can most definitely do performance or load testing for that.

How JMeter works is, it takes an HTTP request and throws the specified number of instances (threads/users) on the server and then measures the response of the server for it.

So if you want to check how much time it takes to click a button for x number of user, I guess there is no tool to test that, because I believe each of those users will be using a different device/system to click the button and that event will be specific to that device/system and the browser on that device only.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that's all JMeter does - run a request and record response time (and some other metrics like start time, response code, whether request successful or not, etc.)

Basically what any web-browser does is sending [HTTP requests](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) and displaying the response.

JMeter can do the same as real browser do (apart from rendering and displaying responses) but all the requests can be simulated by [HTTP Request Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).

See the following reference material:

- [JMeter User Manual - Get Started](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#get_started)
- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#building)
- [JMeter Video Tutorial (Writing Your First JMeter Script)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421695-JMeter-Video-Tutorial-writing-your-first-JMeter-script-)

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri JMeter Response time exclude response times form Failed transactions

If successful transaction takes on avg 20 secs but failed one will fail in 2 
secs. Since Jmeter is including failed response times along with passed one 
for avg response calculation. Avg response time is showing lesser compared 
to actual.

Is there any way to configure Jmeter to just include success samplers 
response time into overall avg response time calculation.?